# Session Timeout on Export an Excel of SSRS reporting Tool on Integrated .net NLB servers

Tags: session, reporting-services, timeout, nlb

I have 3 web.Net servers hosted in NLB and we have used SSRS Reporting Tool for reports . We are getting session Timeout error on Excel to Export option intermittently . Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: How long does the report take to return results?

Comment: Hi , After enabling Sticky session , The reports are working fine .